# How to handle backend errors in Tkinter app?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some backend code that connects to a simple UI generated by Tkinter. The UI basically let's user selects a file and then pass onto backend. Then, some objects will be instantiated from the file. The object has a method (runs upon object creation) that checks for some error and it would prompt a dialog to ask for user's intervention (showing user some data and ask them what to do with it) if there is one.

I thought of three ways to handle this:

1. Create a temporary tk.root and open a new window from there (Not sure if it's a good idea to repeatedly create tk.root, especially the method is run 100+ times)
2. Let the method raise a custom exception with data and handle it in the Tkinter app (is this a good practice?)
3. Somehow pass the tk.root into the object method and create a new window as the child of the root window (I'm stuck here because the method is called upon the object creation, so I'm not explicitly calling it in the Tkinter app.)

Sorry if I sound confusing, this is my first time with Tkinter.

Comment: If you need to open an additional window, use `Toplevel()`  rather than calling `Tk()` again (which causes all sorts of problems because it does far more than just create a window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create a temporary tk.root and open a new window from there

This is never a good idea, there is almost no case where you should create multiple `Tk` windows (because two `Tk` windows cannot communicate). Instead create `Toplevel()` instances, these are like popup windows.

From the sound of your problem I would suggest to create an `ErrorWindow` class that inherits the `Toplevel` class from Tkinter.

something like the following:

```
from tkinter import *

class ErrorWindow(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master, error_info, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ErrorWindow, self).__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        """
        Display code here
        """
```

The master of your `ErrorWindow` would be the root `Tk` window you have.

> especially the method is run 100+ times

To make sure the user isn't flooded with hundreds of error windows you could handle this with a `root.wait_window(x_window)`. This will halt execution of the root window until `x_window` is closed (where `x_window` is your `Toplevel` object).